# From one string column creates two columns, one using the first three elements, and the other using .format()

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I've searched many questions here and I couldn't find a proper answer to me, so pls help me

### A string column in df

| Farms |
| --- |
| Albatros |
| Bali |
| Casablanca |

### Desired output

| Farms | ACR | sourcekey |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Albatros | Alb | Db_Alb_key |
| Bali | Bal | Db_Bal_key |
| Casablanca | Cas | Db_Cas_key |

My main focus here is to have a unique source key, because after, I need to create those tables on the Database.

So what is the best solution, thinking in performance. Should I do a foreach? Should I create the ACR(acronym) table?

I am using python version 3.8.10

If you need any more information, please let me know. I am just a noob and sometimes is really frustrating when we get stuck.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use slicing and vectorial string addition:

```
df['ACR'] = df['Farms'].str[:3]
df['sourcekey'] = 'Db_' + df['ACR'] + '_key'
```

output:

```
        Farms  ACR   sourcekey
0    Albatros  Alb  Db_Alb_key
1        Bali  Bal  Db_Bal_key
2  Casablanca  Cas  Db_Cas_key
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
df['ACR'] = df.Farms.apply(lambda x: x[:3])
df['sourcekey'] = df.ACR.apply(lambda x: 'Db_'+x+'key')
```

Output:

```
>>df
    Farms      ACR      sourcekey
0   Albatros    Alb     Db_Albkey
1   Bali        Bal     Db_Balkey
2   Casablanca  Cas     Db_Caskey
```